# How to get the assigned variable back out of an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I created an array of objects:

```
Object[] r = new Object[2];
```

I assigned a variable of a class to r:

```
r[0] = Start;
```

Start is of type `SDTNode` which is a class I created.

Now I want to get the value back:

```
SDTNode end = r[0];
```

It is giving me an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: which error does it give? have you tried casting it to SDTNode?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that all elements of `r` are `SDTNode` objects, then you should have defined it like this:

```
SDTNode[] r = new SDTNode[2];
```

Otherwise, the type information about the content will be "some `Object`, we don't know the specifics" and you'll have to cast:

```
SDTNode end = (SDTNode) r[0];
```

This will **always** compile, but will fail at runtime if `r[0]` does *not* in fact reference a `SDTNode`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it:

```
SDTNode end = (SDTNode)r[0];
```